How to use useRef variable in useEffect once its been assigned and cant use ref from forwardRef in useEffect
This is my code
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import PostContainer from "./postContainer.jsx"

export function App(props) {
  const postContainerRef=useRef()
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(postContainerRef.current)
  },[postContainerRef])
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <PostContainer 
      ref={postContainerRef}
      some_prop={"meow"} />
    </div>
  );
}

here I want to use the postContainerRef once it's been set but its just logging undefined. I tried using [postContainerRef.current] as the dependency array but it also did nothing.
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, forwardRef } from "react";

const PostContainer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(ref.current)
    },[ref])
    return <>
    <div>This is Container</div>
    </>
})

export default PostContainer

I also want to access the Container element once its been rendered but it is also logging undefined.
Playcode playground

Well you never do set the ref to anything?! What did you expect the ref to refer to?

Adding it to the dependency list won't achieve anything, the reference object is stable (i.e. the same object during every render)

@Bergi I am setting the ref to PostContainer ref={postContainerRef} isnt this how you do it?

You pass it, but then PostContainer doesn't set the ref value to anything. What do you actually want to do with the ref, what do you need it for?

@Bergi Oh i thought I could just set ref to a component but found out you do need to set it to a dom element after reading the answer

Well there's other things that you could set it to, but yes, if you want a dom element, then you need to set it to one

The issue you're facing is related to how useRef and forwardRef work together with useEffect. Here are the key points to address:
1 - The useRef object (postContainerRef) does not trigger re-renders when its current property is updated. Therefore, it won't work as a dependency in useEffect.
2 - When using forwardRef, you should pass the ref to the actual DOM element you want to reference.
Here's a revised version of your code to ensure the ref is properly set and can be used in useEffect:
App Component
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import PostContainer from "./PostContainer";

export function App(props) {
  const postContainerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (postContainerRef.current) {
      console.log(postContainerRef.current);
      // You can now use postContainerRef.current here
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <PostContainer ref={postContainerRef} some_prop={"meow"} />
    </div>
  );
}


PostContainer Component
import { useEffect, forwardRef } from "react";

const PostContainer = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      console.log(ref.current);
      // You can now use ref.current here
    }
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      This is Container
    </div>
  );
});

export default PostContainer;


Explanation
1-App Component:

useRef(null) is used to create a ref object.
useEffect runs once after the initial render. Since the ref will be assigned by then, you can safely access postContainerRef. current within this effect.

2-PostContainer Component:

forwardRef is used to pass the ref to the actual DOM element (div in this case).
useEffect is used to log ref.current after the component mounts. Here, ref is passed down from the parent component, and the ref is assigned to the div element.

This way, the ref is properly assigned to the DOM element, and you can use it in your useEffect hooks both in the parent and the child components.
